# Reduce android graphical interface: hide status bars, notification, etc

Tags: android

I am working on a "kinda embedded system" for a project. For the sake of simplicity let's say that it is some kind of clock.

We are considering android as an operative system, but we would like to offer an extremely minimalistic experience, with just access to some 3-4 applications pre-installed and nothing else. This means
reducing as much as possible the normal android environment:

- no status bar
- no battery notification
- no notification bar (the top draggable bar, sorry I don't know the name for this)

In other words: the users only should be able to access home, the applications provided, switching between these applications, and turning volume up and down.

Since nobody in the team has reasonable experience with android, here comes my question:

Is this possible? and if it is: is it possible without tweaking the graphical environment of the OS in a complex way? Thanks in advance.

*Note*: If the question does not have the proper format, or this is not the place for it, I will be happy to correct it.

Comment: It possible with custom launcher. You can start from here - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358

Comment: I did check that link before. However I did not get the feeling that it is possible to hide the status bar and all the stuff... just controlling the "home button". Thanks.

Comment: In API level 19 (KitKat 4.4) there is a new immersive mode you can set for your apps.  Search for SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE and setSystemUiVisibility() for more info.

Comment: @MichaelKrause, is a launcher a normal app? can I use this immersive mode in a launcher so that the bars are hidden? Thanks.

Comment: No, not normal.  launcher is what provides the GUI shell for Android.  If you have control over the hardware, you could build your own AOSP and provide your own launcher to present to the user.  You wouldn't have to start from scratch - I would recommend having a look at Launcher2 in the AOSP and basing your launcher off of that.  Immersive mode is more of an application-specific concept that you can use if you ship custom apps on this system of yours.